# How can I make Ansible keep only links defined in a list and remove other links?

Tags: ansible

I want to achieve the following - in a directory `sites-enabled` to have only the symlinks present that are defined in a list `{{ sites_enabled }}`

Specifically the difficulty is with - how can I make Ansible have only the defined in the list links present, and what is not in the list - removed.

I have come up with following solution, that is sub-optimal:

```
# 3. Disable all links (clean plate)
- name: Disable all enabled vhosts.
  file: path="{{ remote_enabled_cfg_dir }}/{{ item }}" state=absent
  with_fileglob:
    - "{{ remote_enabled_cfg_dir }}/*"

# 4. Enable only the approved vhosts / Create Link from sites-available to sites-enabled
- name: Enable only allowed vhosts
  file:
    src: "{{ remote_cfg_dir }}/{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ remote_enabled_cfg_dir }}/{{ item }}"
    owner: root
    group: wheel
    state: link
  with_items: "{{ sites_enabled }}"
  notify: reload nginx
```

however, I don't fancy removing all valid symlinks only to recreate them a moment later and have to reload nginx on every play. (I would prefer if there was no change since last play, no action to be taken by Ansible) Is there a more clever way to achieve this goal?

Comment: You should be able to read all the symlinks in an array, then loop over them and match (possible as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161274/how-to-check-whether-an-item-is-present-in-an-ansible-array ) - my Ansible knowledge is not sufficient to give full answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [difference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) Jinja filter for this purpose. Add a task to list the contents of your config dir and register the result in a variable. Then add a task that removes invalid items from the config directory by finding the difference between your list of valid files and those found in the previous step:

```
- name: Get contents of config directory
  command: ls "{{ remote_cfg_dir }}"
  register: cfg_dir_contents
- name: Remove invalid files from config directory
  file:
    dest: "{{ remote_cfg_dir }}/{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ cfg_dir_contents.stdout_lines | difference(sites_enabled) }}"
```

(Assumes that 'sites_enabled' is simply a list of names of files that should exist in 'remote_cfg_dir')